# Getx snackbar dismiss listener

Tags: flutter-getx

I cannot listen to the closing of the snackbar I created with getx.

How do I listen to the closure of a snackbar I created with getx? I have codes that need to run when the snackbar is closing. Is there a structure where we can listen to Getx snackbars?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **snackbarStatus** for status of snackbar

```
Get.snackbar(
      'Title',
      'Message',
      snackbarStatus: (status) {
        if (status == SnackbarStatus.CLOSED) {
          // ..
        }
      },
    );
```